# When you put your hand out of a car that is moving you can feel the air, what would it feel like in a vacuum?

Tags: vacuum, drag

Imagine that you could put your hand out of a spaceship whilst it was travelling and it wouldn't get injured. What would the sensation be like? Would you feel anything, or would you not be able to tell that you were moving? If there are no particles then surely you wouldn't bash into anything to create a sensation?

Answer (score 2):

There are not many particles that your hand can collide with. there are still particles there but they are very very scattered apart that they generally don't matter. you sure will collide with a lot more particles if you were travelling at a velocity comparable to the speed of light.

It depends on the velocity of your hand, its area of cross section and the particle density. The average particle density is $10^6$ particles per $m^3$.

but definitely at the speed that a satellite or a space station orbits earth, you sure would not feel anything.